# jQuery Datatables.net library - insert apostrophe into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I have two servers that I'm running locally - one on my mac using MAMP and one on my PC using WAMP.  Both contain the same Datatables.net library and same php.

I can enter an apostrophe and have it escaped just fine into MySQL on the mac (MAMP) side, but not on the PC using WAMP - same code.

Is there a setting in PHP or MySQL that's not set by default on WAMP that's making the difference?

Comment: Different PHP configuration perhaps? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer then so we can mark this question complete.

Different PHP configuration perhaps? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Magic quotes can cause this problem. Differences between WAMP and MAMP are much less common than server configuration differences between two servers. Usually if code works on one and not the other, there are differences in your Apache or PHP configuration.